# AWS - What's the best Scaling Trigger for PHP Server?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I'm building a web server for my application (PHP) with EB (Elastic Beanstalk).

I'm getting confused about Scaling Trigger.
I know what is and how it works.

I'd like to know whats is the best configuration for web server.
My application is restful and in server it runs the backend.
It only returns JSONS data from database (don't work with images or thing like this), 
I think it'll use more RAM than CPU.

What kind of configuration do you use in yours severs?
NetworkIn or Out? How to mensure what my server holds on?

My configuration actually:

```
Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 1 - 10
Scale based on Average CPUUtilization
Add instance when > 60
Remove instance when < 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely dependent on your specific scenario. So, my configuration may not be ideal for yours. But, stick to some conventional rules when doing this. If I were you, I would instead check the availability of my configuration, seeing whether instances are successfully set as healthy once they are launched, if auto scaling group launches and removes instances correctly when cloudwatch triggers them. sometimes this may be tradeoff between the CPU percentage and you need to adjust it up or down. This sometimes causes problems, if not set correctly, your auto scaling group ends up launching and removing instances regularly!!
Also, make sure scaling up is a better choice than scaling out in your scenario. sometimes, it is simply better to use more powerful instances than scaling out auxiliary ones. 
If you stick to these rules of thumb, you can assure your configuration is an stable one.

(in terms of security, if that's a web server application, see if you need an extra tier of security, for example the WAF layer, whether you want it to be a separate layer, or you want it to be in a separate VPC which receives traffic, analyzes it and then redirects it to a private ELB in the peered VPC, or you simply want to join WAF with your instances.
Or if you are using HTTP/HTTPS ELB request rather than TCP. because HTTP ELB request are more secure as the ELB drop the connection once the client send traffic to ELB and then send a separate header to the backend instances. This removes SYN ATTACK threat! or
cloudfront, as it grows according to the traffic, so no server unavailable DoS threats to your application anymore, and many other tricks which you can come to know via documentation and also the http://en.clouddesignpattern.org/index.php/Main_Page)
good luck!